# #include "drive_base/Drive.h" problem to find

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, now I have a problem to find the "drive_base/Drive.h".
I don't know how to use the "drive.h" and where to put it.
I used a node in the ros, the drive.cpp to move my *.model*, but
still the same :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60978/#include-%22drive_base/drive.h%22-problem-to-find/) by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) on 2013-04-17**:
"drive_base/Drive.h: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's spelled `driver_base/Driver.h`. You need a dependency on the driver_base package, in the driver_common stack.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0